# Dealing with variables in click event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've created a canvas dynamically using the following function:

```
var animating=false;
function create_canvas(Container,Id,Width,Height)
{
 ...//set width,height
 //added a click event listener
 document.getElementById(Id).addEventListener("click", function () 
        {
            if(animating==true)
            {
                alert("Running the animation"); //can't reach this part 
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                animating=true;
                run_canvas();
                animating=false;
            }
        });
 ...//append to Container
}
function run_canvas()
{
 ...//some code here 
}
```

Now whenever I click on the canvas the animation starts no matter what. What I mean is that the global variable **animating** doesn't get it's value changed. Hence my question: What am I doing wrong, how should I deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: Can you post your animation code?

Comment: In my animation code I don't change the variable animating and it's a long code :) implementing a k-means clustering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `run_canvas` method presumably executes its animation code asynchronously, but the statement after it which sets the `animating` property to false is executed immediately upon the animation starting. You need to set the property to false in your `run_canvas` method when it completes its animation, or trigger an event on completion and set the property in the event handler.

Comment: How do you know it's non-blocking?

Comment: @Juhana - Seems like it from the details given no? Maybe I should temper my answer.

Comment: Do you suggest and the end of run_canvas() I should add the animating=false;

Comment: Yeah exactly. Or have the function trigger an event when it completes and set the property in the event handler.

Comment: Yes thanks that did the trick :) I must set the animating=false inside the function once it completes.